# Facebook SDK: UINavigationController has no member 'push'

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am using Facebook's SDK to allow a user to sign into my App using Facebook. The log in button works perfectly. It allows the user to log in and out and the right profile is found. However, when the user logs in, I need the app to show a different view controller here is the code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        var loginButton = FBLoginButton(permissions: [ .publicProfile ])
        
        let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height // real screen height
        //let's suppose we want to have 10 points bottom margin
        let newCenterY = screenHeight - loginButton.frame.height - 20
        let newCenter = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: newCenterY)
        loginButton.center = newCenter

        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        
        if(AccessToken.current != nil) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Logged In", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Logged In")
            self.navigationController?.push(vc, animated: true) // this is the error line
        }
        
        // Extend the code sample "1. Add Facebook Login Button Code"
        // In your viewDidLoad method:
        loginButton = FBLoginButton(permissions: [ .publicProfile, .email, .userFriends ])
    }
```

This is the error message: Value of type 'UINavigationController' has no member 'push'

I am using the latest SDK version. So I don't know what is wrong?

Comment: you have to use  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

Comment: `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)`

Comment: This fixed the error, however it will not go to the next view controller. It is titled 'Logged In Scene' and the view controller is named 'Logged In', any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: please double check your storyboard name and view controller name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)` instead of `push`

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Logged In") as NextViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true)
```

Comment: This fixed the error, however it will not go to the next view controller. It is titled 'Logged In Scene' and the view controller is named 'Logged In', any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You have to navigate from main storyboard so you can use self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Logged In") as yourViewController // yourViewController - next view controller after logged in

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use this? -

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

UPD:

```
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This fixed the error, however it will not go to the next view controller. It is titled 'Logged In Scene' and the view controller is named 'Logged In', any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: This fixed the error, however it will not go to the next view controller. It is titled 'Logged In Scene' and the view controller is named 'Logged In', any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: print your navigationController object. It may be nil.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `push()` method, you will have to use `pushViewController()` method

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true).
```

Note:-

Your storyboard filename can't contain space please remove that space. Rename your storyboard file name as 'LoggedIn' or 'Logged_In'.

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoggedIn", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Logged In")
        self.navigationController?.push(vc, animated: true)
```

How to check the storyBoard name and view controller Identifier?

[image]

Comment: This fixed the error, however it will not go to the next view controller. It is titled 'Logged In Scene' and the view controller is named 'Logged In', any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: check your storyBoard file is same as "Logged In" and viewcontroller identifier is sam as ""Logged In"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `push()` write below line

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

For change title of screen you have to set title property of second screen,

```
vc.title = "Logged In"
```